# AWS Config Error due to missing region in function call

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-regions

```
 import * as aws from 'aws-sdk';
 ...
 const awsConfigurationParmeters: ConfigurationOptions = {
    logger,
    maxRetries: 10,
    region
  };

  if (Object.keys(customHttpOptions).length > 0) {
    awsConfigurationParmeters.httpOptions = customHttpOptions;
  }

  const awsConfig = new aws.Config();
  awsConfig.update(awsConfigurationParmeters);
```

I am setting the region golabally via `aws.config.update`. However, when I trie to make DynamoDB/S3/Firehose/KMS calls, it results in a ConfigError.

```
"before all" hook: Error calling new aws.KMS.listAliases - Error Code: ConfigError
```

The Fix is to put region in the call, so that - `new aws.KMS({region}).listAliases`.

Should't aws.config.update take care of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I want awsConfigurationParameters to be used globally, I need to update `aws.config`. In my example, only a awsConfig is getting updated.

Trying this instead:

```
import * as aws from 'aws-sdk';
 ...
 const awsConfigurationParmeters: ConfigurationOptions = {
    logger,
    maxRetries: 10,
    region
  };

  if (Object.keys(customHttpOptions).length > 0) {
    awsConfigurationParmeters.httpOptions = customHttpOptions;
  }

  aws.config.update(awsConfigurationParmeters);
```

Once the global config is updated, any clients will use that config:

```
const kmsClient = new aws.KMS();
```